# Stata: Generating individual comparison groups for each observation in sample (age brackets)

Tags: loops, reference, comparison, stata

Currently, I try to assign certain properties of a comparison group (i.e.: mean income) to each individual in my microdata sample. The comparison groups are defined by some other observables (gender, region) and generated by other individuals. So far, I coded:

```
     egen com_group = group(gender region)
     bysort com_group: egen com_income = mean(income)
```

This works so far, but, this way raises two issues:

1. As the mean is calculated for all individuals in a certain group and the current observation is part of her own group, its own income counts for the calculation of mean income of own reference group. This might raise a (little) bias. This problem seems minor compared to problem 2.
2. I would prefer to assign the average income of less static groups. More concrete, I’m thinking about generating comparison groups of type group(gender region age+-5years). So, this running age brackets can’t be solved in the above mentioned way as each observation of a different age has a different age bracket. This information can’t be saved in one variable like “ref_group” before. My idea was to loop over all observations and generate observation specific reference groups. But, I don’t really know how to do this…

Comment: #1 at least is an FAQ: see http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-variables-recording-properties/ For a fuller (and deeper) discussion, see http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this give you what you want? I have not checked details. I will add some explanation later. In this example, the range for `age` is +/- 1 and the grouping variable is `race`

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
    idcode   age   race       wage      
        45    35      1   10.18518   
        47    35      1   3.526568     
        48    35      1   5.852843     
         1    37      2   11.73913     
         2    37      2   6.400963     
         9    37      1   10.49114     
        36    37      1   4.180602     
         7    39      1    4.62963     
        15    39      1   16.79548     
        20    39      1   9.661837     
        12    40      1   17.20612     
        13    40      1   13.08374     
        14    40      1   7.745568     
        16    40      1   15.48309     
        18    40      1   5.233495     
        19    40      1   10.16103     
        97    40      2   19.92563    
        22    41      1   9.057972     
        24    41      1   11.09501     
        44    41      1   28.45666   
        98    41      2   4.098635    
         3    42      2   5.016723     
         6    42      1   8.083731     
        23    42      1    8.05153     
        25    42      1   9.581316     
        99    42      2   9.875124    
         4    43      1   9.033813     
        39    44      1   9.790657     
        46    44      1   3.051529     
end

sort age idcode
list, sepby(age)

*----- what you want -----

gen mwage = .
levelsof race, local(lrace)

forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    foreach j of local lrace {

        summarize wage if ///
            inrange(age, age[`i']-1, age[`i']+1) /// age condition
            & race == `j'                        /// race condition
            & _n != `i'                          /// self-exclude condition
            , meanonly

        replace mwage = r(mean) if race == `j' in `i'

    }
}

list, sepby(age)
```

### Edit

If Stata is too slow with your database, then you can do it with [Mata](http://www.stata.com/features/overview/introduction-to-mata/). Here is my attempt at it (I'm only starting to use it):

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse nlsw88
expand 2

*----- what you want -----

egen gro = group(race industry) // grouping variables

* Get number of groups
summarize gro, meanonly
local numgro = r(max)

* Compute upper limits for groups
forvalues i = 1/`numgro' {
     summarize gro if gro == `i', meanonly
     local countgro `countgro' `r(N)'
}

/*
sort group and bracking var. sort in Stata so Mata results
can be posted back to Stata using only -getmata-
*/

sort gro age 

* Take statistic and bracking variables to Mata
putmata STVAR=wage BRVAR=age 

mata:

/*
Get upper limits of groups from Stata.
Not considered good style. See Mata Matters: Macros, Gould (2008)
*/

UPLIM = tokens(st_local("countgro")) 
UPLIM = runningsum(strtoreal(UPLIM)) // upper limits of groups

/*
For example, in the following observation ranges, each line 
shows lower and upper limits:

1-11 
12-23 
24-28 
29-29 
*/


ST = J(rows(STVAR), 1, .)
for (i = 1; i <= cols(UPLIM); i++) {

    if (i == 1) {
        ro = 1
    }
    else {
        ro = UPLIM[i-1]+1
    }

    co = UPLIM[i]

    STVARP = STVAR[|ro\co|]     // statistic variable
    BRVARP = BRVAR[|ro\co|]     // bracket variable

    STPART = J(rows(STVARP), 1, 0)
    for (j = 1; j <= rows(BRVARP); j++) {

            SMALLER = BRVARP :>= BRVARP[j] - 1
            LARGER = BRVARP :<= BRVARP[j] + 1

            STPART[j] = ( sum(STVARP :* SMALLER :* LARGER) - STVARP[j] ) / ( sum(SMALLER :* LARGER) - 1 ) //division by zero gives . for last group with only one observation

    }

    ST[|ro\co|] = STPART // stack results
}

end

getmata mwage=ST

keep wage race industry gro age mwage
sort gro age wage

//list wage gro age matawage, sepby(gro)
```

Mata is formidable with loops; a database with 15.000 observations takes only a few seconds.

Comment: This looks in the right spirit. OP also wants `gender` to be the same, so there is extra code like that for `race`. A extra reference here is http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0033

Comment: I've corrected a small detail that was provoking an erroneous calculation. Indeed @NickCox, the original poster must add a bit of code to get results with an additional grouping variable. I take this to be the research effort that is always expected when posting but that was not entirely shown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the helpful comments! It was easy to add additional code to distinguish additional subgroup(s) by using sub loops. - Only the efficiency of my algorithm seems not very high as it takes very long to generate the group means in a sample of N = 14.000.

Comment: It's hard to avoid a loop over observations here. In principle, the answer for each person might be unique as you want the average for all other people of the same characteristics or (for age) loosely similar characteristic. Also age subsets overlap, so answers can't be determined disjointly for that reason alone.

Comment: Loops are hard to avoid, but you can rely on Mata for this task. It is much faster then using Stata alone. I've added an example.